# Как скрипту кликеру указать временное ограничение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно дописать к скрипту кликеру временное ограничение 100 подписок, затем минута перерыв после чего действия вновь повторяется. В данный момент скрипт работает без лимитов, как решить данную проблему не знаю так как в программировании не селен. Спасибо если кто поможет!
Сам скрипт:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);

var t = 0;
$.each($("button"),function(i,v){
 if($(v).text() == "Follow")
  {
   setTimeout(function(){
      $(v).click();
    },t);
    t+=100;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо конструкции `$.each($("button"), function(){...})` используйте `$("button").each(function(){...}`.
И сразу давайте переменным понятные имена, а не однобуквенные `t`, `i`, `v` - так будет проще потом поддерживать код)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);

var timeout = 0;
$("button").each(function(index, element){
  if($(element).text() != "Follow"){
    return;
  }

  // Если остаток от деления числа на 100 будет 0
  // то есть если число делится нацело на 100
  // А это каждое сотое число - 0, 100, 200, 300
  //                      Но кроме 0
  if(index % 100 == 0 && index !== 0){
    timeout += 60 * 1000;
  }

  setTimeout(function(){
    $(element).click();
  }, timeout);

  timeout += 100;
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает.